# I want to extract array value from json

Tags: java, json

```
{
  "data": {
    "tech-spec": "377.pdf",
    "additional-details": {
      "item": [
    "Currency:GBP",
    "Scaleprice:",
    "Priceunit:"
      ]
    },
    "currency-code": "GBP"
  }
}
```

Above is my json string and I want to extract value of Currency, Scaleprice, Priceunit which is value of "item" array using java

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? Most have examples of doing this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that its not valid JSON, since data seems not be in { or [.

You can manipulate the String using

```
JSONObject jsonData= new JSONObject(data);
if (jsonData.has("data")) { 
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data.getString("data"));
   String tech-spec = json.getString("tech-spec");
   JSONObject additionalDetails = json.getJSONObject("additional-details");

   if (additionalDetails.has("item")) { 
   JONArray item = new JSONArray(additionalDetails.getString("item"));
   for (int i = 0; i <=  item.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject itemObj = new JSONObject(item.getJsonObject(i));
    String Currency = itemObj.getString("Currency");    
    // and the others,...
    }
   }
   String currencyCode = json.getString("currency-code");
 }
```

Comment: This is givining me error org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["item"] not found.

Comment: fixed. Please try to understand the code rather then just copy/paste.